# (4 || x = 5) ReferenceError instead of SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Why does the following code return a `ReferenceError` instead of a `SyntaxError`?

```
4 || x = 5; // Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

Here is how an `AssignmentExpression` is defined according to **ECMAScript 5.1**:

```
AssignmentExpression :
    ConditionalExpression
    LeftHandSideExpression = AssignmentExpression
    LeftHandSideExpression AssignmentOperator AssignmentExpression
```

In this case `4 || x` is not a *LeftHandSideExpression*, but a `LogicalORExpression` that is not included in the `LeftHandSideExpression`. How does the parser work?

Answer (score 0):

My javascript knowledge tells me that "=" has lowest precedence than logical OR "||" that's why you get ReferenceError..

doing this:

```
4 || (x = 5)
```

you don't get an Error at all

edited: carefully reading your question..what you really want to know is how the parser works..well..JS is an interpreted language and is trying to be fast so..when it finds

```
true || destroyWorld() // will never be called.. actually..the parser will never read it
```

when I added the parenthesis I increased the precedence of the whole expression..the assignment operator has one of the lowest

(check link in another answer)

Comment: That's because using the parenthesis you are introducing an `Expression` which is allowed by `LogicalORExpression`.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting find! I believe the scanner is reading from left to right. First it is evaluating `4 || x`. The result of this expression will always be `4`, since `4` is "truthy". Thus, it next evaluates `4 = 5`, which throws the error since you can't redefine the value of an integer.

More reading on the order of precedence here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: I think so too. It's seems like the parser stops when it can't find nothing more, what has been caught is evaluated and then the parser tries to continue.

Answer (score 0):

It's syntactically invalid, and by the spec, you should get a SyntaxError, but your browser is being weird about the exception type.

You're supposed to get an [early](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-error-handling-and-language-extensions) ReferenceError for cases like

```
1 = 2;
```

where the grammar says the left-hand side is okay, but the left-hand side is neither an array literal nor an object literal and [IsValidSimpleAssignmentTarget](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-assignment-operators-static-semantics-early-errors) is not true for the left-hand side. You're supposed to get a SyntaxError when the grammar rejects your code (and in some other cases, too). It looks like your browser may be using a too-permissive version of LeftHandSideExpression and filtering out grammatically-invalid left-hand sides in the same check as IsValidSimpleAssignmentTarget, and producing the same error.